# To which quarter of the line segment does a given point belong?

Tags: python, math, geometry, line, point

If we divide a line segment (with clear source and destination points) to some (equal) parts e.g. 4 quarters, how can we efficiently determine to which quarter a given point belongs?

For example, given a line segment passes from `(0, 0)` to the `(0, 4)`. Dividing the line segment into the 4 parts, the point `(0, 0.5)` belongs to the quarter 1.

How will be the code for such a determination in Python?

Comment: The code might calculate the distances between the point in question and the two end points and derive the quarter from their ratios.

Comment: What have you tried? How would you solve that mathematically?

Comment: @matszwecja So far, no idea but, the first comment simply gave me one :)

Comment: Do you mean segments in 2D ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Let the segment be from A to B. Compute vectorially

```
t = AP.AB / AB²
```

This gives you a reduced abscissa along AB (0 at A, 1 at B, <0 or >1 outside the segment).

Answer (score 0):

Line segment start coordinate: `a1 = (x1, y1)`

Line segment end coordinate: `a2 = (x2, y2)`

Given point: `z = (x3, y3)`

Number of parts: `n = 4`

```
line_seg_length = ((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2)**0.5
start_to_point_len = ((x1 - x3)**2 + (y1 - y3)**2)**0.5
part = int(start_to_point_len / line_seg_length * n) + 1
```

The result will be a value between 1 to 4 as the quarter number of the line segment to which the give point belongs.

I appreciate it to see a more efficient solution/code.